# Delete in Dapper ASP.Net core boilerplate not working

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to excecute below stored procedure in dapper in boilerplate. I followed the link [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dapper-Integration), but getting error

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteEmployeeById]
 @ID int
AS
BEGIN
 
   DELETE FROM 
[dbo].[Airport] where EmployeeID=@ID
END
```

> Procedure or function 'DeleteEmployeeById' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied

Code which i used is as follows:

```html
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            dictionary.Add("@ID", 10);
            try
            {
                
                var people = _repository.Query("DeleteEmployeeById", new DynamicParameters(dictionary));

            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException exception)
            {
              
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
var people = _repository.Query("DeleteEmployeeById", new { id = 10});
```